# How to profile from the command line on Mac OS X?

Tags: c++, c, macos, profiling, gprof

I'm trying to profile C/C++ code on Mac OS X using command line tools, I use `-pg` option with `gcc` to run `gprof` on Linux, but I can't seem to find the `gprof` on Mac even though I have a description in this page: [Additional Command-Line Tools (iOS)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/PerformanceOverview/PerformanceTools/PerformanceTools.html) or [Additional Command-Line Tools (mac)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/PerformanceOverview/PerformanceTools/PerformanceTools.html).

```
gprof:Produces execution profiles based on an execution analysis of a program.
```

I installed command line tools, so other command line tools such as `otool` and `atos` are available. I googled to find this page (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154289/installing-gprof-on-mac) that says `gprof` is not supported, but I'm not sure when I have an Apple doc describing the tool; anyway, I tried to use `brew` to download `gprof`, but it didn't work.

I found [Attempting to use gprof with C++ code on a Mac](https://rachelbythebay.com/w/2012/09/14/mac/), but I have no output with `instruments -t`. I also found [Profiling c++ on mac os x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445619/profiling-c-on-mac-os-x), but I don't want to open Instruments, as I would like to automate some of the processes and try to keep cross platform system.

- How to use gprof on Mac OS X? I use OS X 10.10.
- How can I profile from the command line, with or without `gprof`?

Comment: You can build gprof yourself on mac. It builds fine. However I am not sure it would work with clang. You may have to install gcc as well.

Comment: This might be of interest: https://diogogmt.wordpress.com/2012/09/17/using-instruments-time-profiler/. Also, on an unrelated note, I noticed you had posted something yesterday about keyboard maestro — I was about to post a solution before you deleted the question, so if you're still looking for that let me know.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Mach-0 executables don't work with gprof (that's what Mac OS X uses), so no gprof

Comment: Instruments is simply bulky and slow. In addition, it's a GUI.

Comment: What about valgrind (not the real hw profiler, but simulator of hardware) or https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools?

Comment: @osgx I spent a great deal of time attempting to install it, actually. I couldn't find a good tutorial for installing it on Mac OS X.

Comment: @Kyll what made you think that was part of the intent of the question owner? the title even says "command line profiling tool for max os x"

Comment: @Kyll No! You're disrupting the intent of the author! Revert it!

Comment: @Kyll It's been here for a year now. Has it been removed? It's asking for install instructions, not a product reccomendation.

Comment: @Kyll I posed another suggested edit, it asks for instructions instead of `what other command line tools`

Comment: @Kyll you changed the scope of the question then downvoted two existing questions - what a bully

Comment: @Kyll I'm going to court (dispute on meta)

Comment: FYI, [this question (and edits) is being discussed on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327136/is-this-a-too-broad-because-its-a-tool-request)

Answer (score 8):

It is strange to hear that there is no `gprof` profiler for OSX. OSX is certified unix and the profiler of unix is `gprof` (based on `profil` syscall/library function which is there: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/profil.2.html).

There are problems with GNU gprof (part of binutils) according to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154289/installing-gprof-on-mac (2014; thanks to Sreekanth Nagareddy user - deleted answer), `brew install -v binutils` "*** This configuration is not supported in the following  subdirectories: .. ld gas gprof"; OSX is not listed in GNU gprof readme: http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/src/gprof/README (2012) in "Supported Platforms" (only OSF/1,  SunOS,  Solaris,  HP-UX listed; I think it should work on Hurd and works on Linuxes).

But there is also BSD implementation of gprof (check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/gprof for history and references). Didn't try to get it running on OSX (have no OSX nor bitten apples newer than 1995 desktop&notebook).

There are different sources of BSD gprof, for example, FreeBSD's version (https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/tree/af3e10e5a78d3af8cef6088748978c6c612757f0/usr.bin/gprof) or ancient 4.3BSD original http://www.retro11.de/ouxr/43bsd/usr/src/ucb/gprof/. Both variants have no support of Mach-O format used in OSX.

There is even Apple's own gprof (based on BSD gprof from NetBSD/OpenBSD) in cctools of Darwin (Darwin is UNIX part both kernel and user-space of OSX; it is/was/will open-source): https://github.com/LeoTestard/Darwin/tree/master/cctools/gprof / https://github.com/darwin-on-arm/darwin-sdk/tree/master/cctools/gprof / http://src.gnu-darwin.org/src/usr.bin/gprof/gprof.c.html (some older mix of FreeBSD code and GNU crazy ideas of freedom).

The availability of gprof may depend on exact OSX version or Xcode version/packages; there were gprof for 10.6.1, according to http://louise.hu/poet/gprof-on-osx/ or on some version from 2012 - https://rachelbythebay.com/w/2012/09/14/mac/ or even in 2001: http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-development/2001/Apr/msg00617.html

There is variant of using `instruments` (part of Xcode Tools?) in command-line, don't know how exactly, but know that instruments is modern and feature-rich profiler.

There is also `iprofiler` command-line interface to collect profiles for `Instruments.app`, just noted man page of it https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/iprofiler.1.html (part of Xcode Tools version 5.0; manpage from legacy part of site).

There are third-party profilers, declared to support OSX. I know two of them: valgrind and gperftools (google-perftools).

valgrind is not a profiler; it is a (slow) dynamic instrumentation platform with many tools built on top of it. It includes two tools, capable of profiling: `callgrind` and `cachegrind`. Valgrind and both tools are not native profiler, they do not profile application as it will run on real cpu in real life. Instead, valgrind executes program on the virtual machine and callgrind/cachegrind instruments machine code with counters.

callgrind (http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html) uses counter per linear block of instructions to count "how many times every instruction will be executed" ("Ir" event, used to get profile - sort functions by percent of time used); it also records calls/returns to build callgraph. "Ir" event count is correct to get instruction execution counts (it may also emulate branch prediction); but it can't be used to estimate real running time. Real cpu (high performance cpus called superscalar; out-of-order cpus are superscalar too) able to execute more than one instruction per cpu clock cycle; and it is also often incapable of executing any instruction because they may want some data to be started (data from far cache or from memory or from syscall or from other high-latency instruction; or cpu mispredicted branch leads to instruction address not yet read/decoded). Most progressive cpus may even not execute some commands (some can execute up to 8 "`nop`"s per cycle, several Intel's Sandy/Ivy Bridges and newer will not spend any time on "`xor eax,eax`" to write zero into register; they just remap next register usage to zeroed physical register). callgrind has typical 10-20 slowdown on profiling run compared to real run on hardware CPU.

Cachegrind implements same instrumentation as callgrind ("Ir", branches), but also can emulate cache hierarchy (cache loads/stores/misses events). And it is slower than callgrind.

Output from callgrind and cachegrind can be viewed with GUI tool kcachegrind (http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/, it may work in OS) or in command-line tool `callgrind_annotate`.

Other tool is gperftools (google-perftools, https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools), which run the program on real CPU. To use it, install it with homebrew, then link the program with libprofiler (add `-Lpath_to_installed_gperftools -lprofiler`) and run with `CPUPROFILE` environment variable set to some filename (`CPUPROFILE=profile01 ./the_program`). It will profile the program using interval timer (`setitimer`) and output profiling data to the filename, defined in `CPUPROFILE` env var. Then you can view profile data in command-line or with svg/web browser using `pprof` perl script from gperftools (`pprof ./the_program profile01`).

Comment: So, what is the solution? I just need one clean cut instruction to process `gprof` along  `gcc ...-pg` with *macOS*.

Comment: @Kuo same question as you. Sadly this answer looks promising at the first glance, but I end up still knowing nothing about the solution ...

Answer (score 8):

> How can I profile from the command line, with or without gprof?

This seems to work in MacOS Monterey 12.5

```
xctrace record --output <path/to/folder> --template "Time Profiler" --time-limit 10s --attach <pid>
```

The results will be a .trace file which you can open with

```
open path/to/name-of-file.trace
```

If you want to launch the app instead of attach to an existing app then use `--launch -- command arugments`.  `--launch` must be the last argument

for more info

```
man xctrace
```

Comment: Thank you! I finally got this working. Note that if you are habitually using a Rosetta2 x86 emulated terminal this will not work (blank trace). You must use an arm64 terminal.

Answer (score -1):

On a sperate question of mine (CrazyPython), I was able to use gperftools (`pprof`) with the assistance of @osgx. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37685434/problems-with-using-gperftools-on-mac-os-x/) is the question and [here](https://gist.github.com/CrazyPython/359528e67531e895e2ed945ad2e8f5c4) is the GitHub gist of the script. For your convenience, here is the script inline:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Licensed under the Unlicense. Full text at (http://unlicense.org/) - CrazyPython
g++ -std=c++11 $1 -o ./.executables/profiler/$(basename $1 .cpp) -g -O -lprofiler
echo "Finished compiling + linking"
CPUPROFILE=$1.out ./.executables/profiler/$(basename $1 .cpp)
./.executables/profiler/$(basename $1 .cpp)
pprof ./.executables/profiler/$(basename $1 .cpp) $1.out
```

*Warning: I tried to clean it up a bit. It likely contains quite a few unnecessary options.*

Comment: As a side note, the bounty is still on.

Comment: Python, do you want 50 rep from youself?

Comment: @osgx the system doesn't allow it

Comment: later I will expand it and add links. I should recheck something.

Comment: With new edits of the question it can be hard for me to check gprof on OSX (which version of OS?)....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116016/discussion-between-uohtypyzarc-and-osgx).